# Angular 2 Router (ES5) doesn't work on page reload

Tags: angular

I wrote a simple Angular 2 application. Everything works just fine except one thing. When I click on the router link, Url is changed and component is loaded, then when I **reload the page** I get **404** not found. Can not understand why?

Here is my code:

```
(function(app) {


  app.AppComponent =
    ng.core.Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: '<a [routerLink]="[\'Component1\']">Component1</a>' + 
                '<a [routerLink]="[\'Component2\']">Component2</a>' + 
                '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
      directives: [
            ng.router.ROUTER_DIRECTIVES
      ]
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function() {}
    });


    app.AppComponent = ng.router.RouteConfig([

    {
        path: '/component1', component: app.Component1, name: 'Component1' 
    },
    {
        path: '/component2', component: app.Component2, name: 'Component2' 
    }
    ]) ( app.AppComponent );


})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

That's a browser feature.
Angular by default uses HTML5 pushstate (`PathLocationStrategy` in Angular slang).
You either need a server that processes all requests like it were requesting `index.html` or you switch to `HashLocationStrategy` (with # in the URL for routes) https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/HashLocationStrategy-class.html

See also https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/

To switch to `HashLocationStrategy` use

```
bootstrap(AppCmp, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
]);
```

ensure you have all required imports

```
import {provide} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {
  HashLocationStrategy
  LocationStrategy,
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
} from 'angular2/router';
```

Comment: I am using below code for hashlocation:  ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(app.AppComponent, [
    ng.router.ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ,
    ng.core.provide(ng.common.LocationStrategy, {
     useClass : ng.common.HashLocationStrategy
    }) ]);
 but I am getting Cannot read property 'getOptional' of undefined error

@Gunter